# Changing URL while displaying page change animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Wondering how I can achieve the following effect on a website I'm building:

1. Div with 100vw width and 100vh height (we'll call this #container2) hides to the right of the home page (we'll call the home page #container1).
2. Moving mouse towards the right edge of the page causes #container2 to peek out.
3. If the user clicks on the visible portion of #container2, it slides all the way to the left, fully obscuring #container1.
4. The user is now on a new page with a corresponding URL, where they can scroll down and view more content.

I've got the first 3 steps more or less figured out. What I need help with is figuring out the best way to:

- Handle the URL transition from **site.com** into **site.com/newpage** during the sliding animation
- How to dynamically load the new page's content to the #container2 once the page transition happens, so the user can scroll down and see the new pages content if they click into it, but don't have to load the content if they choose to stay on the homepage.
- Making it so if someone types or is linked directly to **site.com/newpage**, they will see the same thing that someone who started on the home page, clicked #container2, and watched the transition animation sees (but without showing a page transition).

I don't have any code snippets to show because I'm not really sure where to start. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. If possible, I'd like to use a vanilla javascript solution, as I've managed to make all the other features on the site run without JQuery. If JQuery is the only way to do this though, I'd still love to hear the solution.

Comment: Have a look at history.pushState, some jquery stuff and htaccess rewrites. However this is far to broad to be properly answered...

Comment: @Jonasw Any details I should add to be more specific?

Comment: No. Try yourself! Then ask if you have a certain problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could do this. My intuition would be to have only one page that has different url fragments. Your question is fairly broad so my answer will also be broad.

One approach would be to use the target pseudo-class in css. All you need to do is make container2 a link that adds fragment to the end of the url that matches the classname of said container. You could have a some style for :hover that makes the container slide out and some settings for :target that brings the container to the center of the page. Container2 could have have a second section beneath the fold that contains the rest of the content for the page.

You could do something very similar with javascript by adding and removing classes from the various elements, but using the target pseudo class will help with your last bullet point. If a user goes directly to the link with the fragment, they will see the page with that container displayed.

I hope that gives you a place to start. Here is [some info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) about the target pseudo-class.